# How do i remove a string from a list if it DOES NOT contain certain characters in Python

Tags: python, string, list, filter, character

I am working on a list filter. This is as far as I've gone. I would like to remove every string that doesn't contain `H`, `L` OR `C`. So far this is my attemp

```
input_list = input("Enter The Results(leave a space after each one):").split(' ')

for i in input_list:
    if 'H'not in i or 'L' not in i or 'C' not in i:
```

Comment: You want to use and rather than or, for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pythonic code

```
input_list = input("Enter The Results(leave a space after each one):").split(' ') # this is the input source
after_removed = [a for a in input_list if ('H' not in a and 'L' not in a and 'C' not in a)] # this is the after removed 'H', 'L', and 'C' from the input_list
```

Using list comprehension, you can make python easier and faster

If you don't believe, just try it for yourself :D

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, you can use a function

```
def contains_invalid_character(my_string):
    return 'H' in my_string or 'L' in my_string or 'C' in my_string
    # To be more pythonic, you can use the following
    # return next((True for letter in ("H", "L", "C") if letter in my_string), False)

results = []
for i in input_list:
    if not contains_invalid_character(i):
         results.append(i)
# Or to be more pythonic
# results = [i for i in input_list if not contains_invalid_character(i)]
```